# Error when running windows PlaySound(), undefined reference to `__imp_PlaySoundA'

Tags: c

So I tried using PlaySound() function from Windows but it returns with 'undefined reference to __imp_PlaySoundA'

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>

int main()
{
    LPCTSTR SongFile="C:\\Users\\User1\\Desktop\\AudioPlayer\\mev.wav";
    PlaySound(SongFile,NULL,SND_NODEFAULT);
    return 0;
}
```

I know that you have to do something with the winmm.lib but I spent like 3 hours looking for this but I have no idea still. I am using mingw as my compiler and am using Visual Studio Code.

Comment: Under MinGW you must link the libwinmm.a file or the **-lwinmm** option of the linker.

Comment: Can you describe how you link it in minGW? Do you do it in the mingw files or in mingw shell? I just started using mingw so I know nothing. Do you recommend any resources I should check?

Comment: with a command line compilation, it gives:  `gcc main.c -o progname -lwinmm`