Cannot get PlaySound() to work in Visual Studio Code
I'm just trying to make a simple sound player in Visual Studio Code, but my program get an error:

The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1.

I commented out line 12 (PlaySound) and the program ran normally.
This is the code I currently have:
#include <Windows.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "winmm.lib")

using namespace std;

//string SONGNAME;

int main(){
    //SONGNAME = "Testing.wav";
    cout << "Playing music \n";
    PlaySound(TEXT("Testing.wav"), NULL , SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC | SND_LOOP);
    return 0;
}

This is my explorer window:

I suspect the issue is partially because I opted for Visual Studio Code instead of Visual Studio, but I am unable to find any info about it online.
cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\Ivan S\OneDrive\Desktop\cplusplusprogramzzz\songplayer\songPlayer.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Ivan S\OneDrive\Desktop\cplusplusprogramzzz\songplayer\songPlayer.exe" C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IVANS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccySdqvK.o: in function main': C:/Users/Ivan S/OneDrive/Desktop/cplusplusprogramzzz/songplayer/songPlayer.cpp:14:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to __imp_PlaySoundA' collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 


The preLaunchTask 'C/C++: g++.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1 - this is the last error. Please post errors from start.

Most likely you didn't link with the required library: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dd743680(v=vs.85)#requirements

cmd /c chcp 65001>nul && C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\Ivan S\OneDrive\Desktop\cplusplusprogramzzz\songplayer\songPlayer.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Ivan S\OneDrive\Desktop\cplusplusprogramzzz\songplayer\songPlayer.exe"
C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/13.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\IVANS~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccySdqvK.o: in function main': C:/Users/Ivan S/OneDrive/Desktop/cplusplusprogramzzz/songplayer/songPlayer.cpp:14:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to __imp_PlaySoundA'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit s

C:\msys64\ucrt64\bin\g++.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -g "C:\Users\Ivan S\OneDrive\Desktop\cplusplusprogramzzz\songplayer\songPlayer.cpp" -o "C:\Users\Ivan S\OneDrive\Desktop\cplusplusprogramzzz\songplayer\songPlayer.exe" is the bug. You didn't link to the required library. If you are using code-runner it's time to forget about  that extension and move to the official method that uses tasks.json

First start with the official VSCode MinGW instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

@drescherjm thanks for the suggestion, is there any resources you could link me to get started?

[edit] and post the errors in a text block in the question.

See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73968474/error-when-running-windows-playsound-undefined-reference-to-imp-playsounda

Here is a descent tutorial on how to compile and link with gcc or g++: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/gcc_make.html The same command line you type is what you put in your args:  part of your tasks.json.  Note that the tutorial is a little old but the concepts will be the same for the modern compiler as the old versions that the tutorial talks about.

Thank you for all the help everyone, ill post an update soon


in function main': C:/Users/Ivan S/OneDrive/Desktop/cplusplusprogramzzz/songplayer/songPlayer.cpp:14:(.text+0x3e): undefined reference to __imp_PlaySoundA'

You are getting a linker error, because you are not actually linking to the winmm library.  gcc does not support MSVC's #pragma comment(lib, ...) statement for linking to libraries (you can specify the -Werror=unknown-pragmas command-line parameter to make that statement fail at compile-time).
For gcc, you need to use the -lwinmm command-line parameter to link to the winmm library.
